# Dynamically created element's ID in variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap modal which loads up and as it's loading it, gets the form from server:

```
$('#edit-post-modal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
    var postID = e.relatedTarget.dataset.post;

    $.get('edit' + '/' + postID, function (data, status) {
        form.html(data);
    });

    var submitURL = e.relatedTarget.dataset.url;
    form.attr("action", submitURL);
});
```

My ajax function accepts an `alertElement` parameter which is the ID of the element where the alert should be displayed.

```
function doAjax(form, alertElement) {

  $.ajax({
     type: form.attr('method'),
     dataType: 'JSON',
     url: form.attr('action'),
     data: form.serialize(),
     success: function (data) {

       alertElement.html(data);

     },
}
```

And I can call the doAjax() function like so:

```
var form = $('#form-post');
var alertElement = $('#report-alert-field');

// ajax request to server
doAjax(form, alertElement);
```

As you can see, after the ajax is done, it is supposed to change the alert text to the text from database. If the alert element is not previously loaded from server, it works fine, but it does not work if it's dynamic.

How can I fix this?

Also when I do console.log in ajax **success** method, I get two different things for the same thing.

```
// These two don't output the same thing

    console.log($('#report-alert-field'));
    console.log(alertElement);
```

`console.log($('#report-alert-field'));` outputs the following:

> [div#report-alert-field, context: document, sector: "#report-alert-field"]
>   0
>   :
>   div#report-alert-field
>   context
>   :
>   document
>   length
>   :
>   1
>   selector
>   :
>   "#report-alert-field"
>   **proto**
>   :
>   Object[0]

`console.log(alertElement)` outputs the following:

> x.fn.x.init {context: document, selector: "#report-alert-field"}
>   context
>   :
>   document
>   selector
>   :
>   "#report-alert-field"
>   **proto**
>   :
>   Object[0]

Comment: pass the `attr('id')` of an `alertElement` instead of passing element and use it something like `$('#'+alertElement)...`

Comment: Are you doing `alertElement = $('#report-alert-field')` after the element is created? ie executing the code in a ready callback like `$(document).ready`?

Comment: No I have it at the top of the page when the page loads.